# Easy way to copy the first nth values of a set into a vector in C++

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, c++14, c++17

Simple question, let's say I save a set with 5 values and I want to copy the first 3 values into a vector, is there a fast easy way to do that?
I know that if I want to copy an entire set into a vector I can just use something like this:

```
set <int> test = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
vector<int> vect(test.begin(),test.end());
```

Can I do something similar to only copy the first n values? I've been using a for loop to do this but I was just curious to check if there was a faster way to code it.

Comment: [std::copy_n](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get an iterator `n` steps from the `begin` of a `std::set`, `std::next` yields the abstraction you need.

```
std::vector<int> vec(test.cbegin(), std::next(test.cbegin(), 5));
```

This is due to `std::set` providing bidirectional iterators, so you can't use arithmetics like `test.cbegin() + 5`. `std::next` solves this for you.

Answer (score 3):

`std::set::iterator` is a [bidirectional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator) iterator not a [random access](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) one, hence use [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next)`, as follows

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::set <int> test = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    size_t n=3;
    std::vector<int> vect;
    if(test.size() >= n) vect = std::vector<int>{test.begin(),std::next(test.begin(),n)};

    std::for_each(vect.begin(), vect.end(), [](auto el){std::cout << el <<" ";});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sMcraM)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the `std::next()` answers is that `std::next()` is inherently unsafe. If there weren't actually 5 elements in the `set` you'd keep iterating past the end iterator - and that's undefined behavior.

If you use range-v3 instead, this is a solution which is both safe and, in my opinion, more expressive:

```
auto vect = test
          | views::take(5)
          | ranges::to<std::vector>();
```

This will take *up to* the first 5 elements of the set and construct a `vector` out of the resulting range. `views::take` is in C++20, although `ranges::to` is unfortunately not.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M57o6r).

Comment: If you remove the last none-std adapter (`to`) and provide a minimal complete example, everyone can see what `std::ranges` is about. The way you typed, only people who already know about ranges understand - which violates the purpose of informing the OP.

Comment: Could you comment on whether the ranges solution also traverses twice over the set or only once? In the next solution `next` iterates over the set (to find the `end` iterator) and during copying it is iterated over again, This is unnecessary. So is the ranges approach better in that regard?

Comment: @AndreasH. The `std::next` solution actually iterates 3 times (once in `next`, once in the `vector` constructor to find the distance to figure out how much to allocate, and then again during the construction). The ranges solution iterates twice.

Comment: @Barry. Good point, I forgot about the allocation. But if one knows the the number of elements beforehand the good old `copy_n` with vector reserve should be the most efficient, because that would iterate only once. This is interesting.